# How to use embedsMany relation from jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

I am trying to configure a embedsMany and use this part of jenssegers/laravel-mongodb documentation:

[Documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvldf.png)

My object is get a Company from my Department Model

This is my Company Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Domains\Company\Models;

use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model;

class Company extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'companies';

    public function departments()
    {
        return $this->embedsMany(Department::class);
    }
}
```

And here is my Department Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Domains\Company\Models;

use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model;

class Department extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'companies';
}
```

I can get my Department Collection from a Company using:

`(new App\Domains\Company\Models\Company())->find('id')->departments();`

But when I try to use my Department Model direct, I got a null response

`new App\Domains\Company\Models\Department::first();`

What a want to know is how I configure my Department Model to can use it without the Company Model like the documentation example.

Thanks.